# Dijit Menu (bar) with link

Tags: menu, dojo, menuitem, menubar

I am using Dijit Menu bar with declartive markup.

The Menu items contains links ('a'):

```
<li dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" id="i_car_new">
   <a href="/RooTest/cars?form">Create new Car</a>
</li>
```

The menu is rendered correct, and even the link is display as link, but when one click on this link in the menu, noting happens. (*My actual workaround is to add an 'onClick' event with an 'window.location'.*)

But I would expect that the links work like normal (user click, browswer request new page). So is my expectance wrong? And what must I change, that the links work?

relevant parts from the html.file

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: false};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RooTest/resources/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RooTest/resources/spring/Spring.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RooTest/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra spring">
    <div version="2.0" id="menu" dojoType="dijit.MenuBar">
    <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dijit.MenuBar");
            dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuBarItem");
            dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
            dojo.require("dijit.MenuItem");
            dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuItem");
     </script>

     <ul id="_menu">
        <li dojoType="dijit.PopupMenuBarItem" id="c_car">
            <h2>Car</h2>
            <ul dojoType="dijit.Menu">
                <li dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" id="i_car_new">
                   <a href="/RooTest/cars?form">Create new Car</a>
                </li>
                <li dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" id="i_car_list"
                    <a href="/RooTest/cars">List all Cars</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">...</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't navigate away from the page when you click is because the MenuItem calls dojo.stopEvent when you click it - see _onClick() at http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojo/tags/release-1.6.1/dijit/MenuItem.js#L92

If you want to do this a lot I'd be tempted to extend the MenuItem with something like (old syntax, I've not moved over to the new AMD way of doing things yet, and untested):

```
dojo.provide('dijit.anchorMenuItem');
dojo.require('dijit.MenuItem');

dojo.declare('dijit.anchorMenuItem', dijit.MenuItem, {
    _onClick: function(evt) {
        this.getParent().onItemClick(this, evt);
    }
});
```

And then use this in place of the default MenuItem when you want a simple link. Otherwise, do as your saying and add a call to `window.location` on the onClick handler, but I think this is neater personally.

Comment: there is a small typo in your code: first `function()` should be removed: so that it looks like:  `dojo.declare('dijit.anchorMenuItem', dijit.MenuItem, {
              _onClick: function(evt) {
                     this.getParent().onItemClick(this, evt);
                 }
            });`

Answer (score 0):

In dojo 1.7, I tried:

```
dojo.provide('dijit.anchorMenuItem');
dojo.declare('dijit.anchorMenuItem', dijit.MenuItem, {
  _onClick: function(evt) {
    this.getParent().onItemClick(this, evt);
    }
  });
```

...that didn't fire on click of top level MenuItem

I tried:

```
dojo.connect(window.location,"onclick"...
```

...that didn't work.

FYI, here is what worked (for me -- not an expert):

```
dojo.connect(window,"onmouseup",function(_evt) {
  var _wdg = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(_evt.target)
  if (_wdg && _wdg.baseClass && _wdg.baseClass == "dijitMenuItem" && _wdg.onItemClick) {
      _wdg.onItemClick(_evt)
      }
    }
  )
```