# Dijit.MenuItem and <a href=></a> link

Tags: xpages, dojo, menuitem

My question is similar to that one:
[Dijit Menu (bar) with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883680/dijit-menu-bar-with-link)

I'm using Dijit Menu as in following listing:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu">
    <div id="menuItem" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem">
        <a href="http://url.com">urlLink</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But link is not working as it blocked by `dojo.stopEvent` in  _onClick().

The question is:
How to remove dojo.stopEvent and make link inside `<div id="menuItem" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem">` work properly?

The issue:
I need to put inside `<div id=menuItem">` some code, which has to receive onClick event.

*P.S. Originally this is XPages code.*

Answer (score 1):

Well I fell in same problem, saw this post and the related other, but wasn't satisfied with the "onclick" solution :

- it didn't work (for me) with keyboard navigation
- it imposes to a add script element (onclick=...) in the declarative zone which is not what I expect for unobtrusive JavaScript

Finaly I digged further in dojo and decided to directly use the href attribute of first  sub-node in the handler. My script section (derived from [dijit menus tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/menus)) is then :

```
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/dom-attr",
    "dojo/query",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dijit/WidgetSet", // for registry.byClass
        "dijit/Menu",
        "dijit/MenuItem", 
        "dijit/MenuBar",
        "dijit/MenuBarItem", 
        "dijit/PopupMenuBarItem",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(dom, parser, domattr, query, registry){
        // a menu item selection handler
        var onItemSelect = function(event){
            dom.byId("lastSelected").innerHTML = this.get("label");
            var achild = query("a", this.domNode)[0];
            if (achild != null) {
                var href = domattr.get(achild, "href");
                if ((href != null) && (href != '') && (href != '#')) {
                    window.location.href = href;
                }
            }
        };

        parser.parse();

        var setClickHandler = function(item){
            item.on("click", onItemSelect);
        };

        registry.byClass("dijit.MenuItem").forEach(setClickHandler);
        registry.byClass("dijit.MenuBarItem").forEach(setClickHandler);
    });
</script>
```

That way I don't have to change anything in a menu of type

```
<ul><li><a href="...">...</a></li></ul>
```

that works with JavaScript disabled, and links work fine with mouse and keyboard navigation when JavaScript is enabled. Simply don't forget the "class='claro'" in body element ....

Comment: Thanks for the update and share your solution! ) I'll check it also in my project!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu">
    <div id="menuItem" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" 
          onclick="window.location('http://url.com')">
        <a href="http://url.com">urlLink</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KuyYX/

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback, but I need to put some other stuff inside <div id="menuItem"> which has to handle onClick event, so it's not fully solves my issue. Thanks! )

Comment: you can add there as much stuff as you want. you could also call an external function.